# using 'requests' Facebook dialog from an Android application

Tags: java, android, facebook

I'm trying to use a 'requests' facebook dialog in my Android application.
The facebook tutorial is pretty straightforward:(http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/ — search for 'request dialog')

supposedly, it is just a line of code to display a dialog with the list of your friends where you can select the ones you want to send invitations to:

```
//Send requests with no friend pre-selected and user
//selects friends on the dialog screen.
mFacebook.dialog(context, "apprequests", new AppRequestsListener());

//send request to a particular friend.
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("to", "");
mFacebook.dialog(context, "apprequests", new AppRequestsListener());
```

Except for the apparent typo (they missed to pass the params Bundle to the functions in the second case), everything looks good.
So I tried both variants and the response I'm getting from Facebook is always the same:

**An error occurred with AppName. Please try again later.  API code: 100. API error description: Invalid parameter. Error message: The parameter message is required.**

am I doing something wrong or is it Facebook that is screwed up?

Comment: I think I just figured it out, if you go to the Android API description of Facebook you'll see the following: "Currently supported methods are feed and oauth."

Comment: And I think you have to call the facebook.authorize() method too before this.

Comment: i did of course. to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Just had to do the very same thing. The error message is pointing you to the message body that is missing. The revised code (below) did the trick for me.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", "This is the message text");
mFacebook.dialog(context, "apprequests", params, new AppRequestsListener());
```

Hope this helps!